# Full Outer Join Duplicate Results

Tags: sql

Good Day,

This may seem long (but it's the data I'm showing) I have two tables.  TestA and TestB.  TestA has two columns (INT, VARCHAR(32)) called RowNumber and InvoiceNumber.  The following result is:  SELECT RowNumber, InvoiceNumber FROM TestA.

```
1   GB01530111600236
2   GB01530111600236
3   GB01530111600236
1   GB01530121600001
2   GB01530121600001
```

TestB is identical in that there are two columns with the same name.

```
1   GB01530111600236
1   GB01530121600001
2   GB01530121600001
3   GB01530121600001
4   GB01530121600001
5   GB01530121600001
6   GB01530121600001
7   GB01530121600001
8   GB01530121600001
9   GB01530121600001
10  GB01530121600001
11  GB01530121600001
12  GB01530121600001
```

My understanding of a FULL OUTER JOIN is that it will match all rows from both tables based on a JOIN and WHERE clause.  The reason is that TableA can have 1 or more invoice numbers and that TableB can also have 1 or more invoice numbers.

So from TestA, there are three invoice numbers of 'GB01530111600236' and one in TestB with 'GB01530111600236'.  In addition, there are 12 invoice numbers in TestB that are 'GB01530121600001' and two in TestA with 'GB01530121600001'  So what I'm trying to get is:

```
[   Table A        ]    [   Table B        ]
1   GB01530111600236    1   G01530111600236
2   GB01530111600236    1   G01530111600236
3   GB01530111600236    1   G01530111600236
1   GB01530121600001    1   GB01530121600001
2   GB01530121600001    2   GB01530121600001
1   GB01530121600001    3   GB01530121600001
1   GB01530121600001    4   GB01530121600001
1   GB01530121600001    5   GB01530121600001
1   GB01530121600001    6   GB01530121600001
1   GB01530121600001    7   GB01530121600001
1   GB01530121600001    8   GB01530121600001
1   GB01530121600001    9   GB01530121600001
1   GB01530121600001    10  GB01530121600001
1   GB01530121600001    11  GB01530121600001
1   GB01530121600001    12  GB01530121600001
```

My query is:

```
SELECT A.RowNumber, B.RowNumber, A.InvoiceNumber, B.InvoiceNumber
FROM TestA A 
    FULL OUTER JOIN TestB B ON A.InvoiceNumber = B.InvoiceNumber
```

This query is half way right in that it gives me the correct output for 'GB01530111600236'.  The abridged version displays only 1-5 instead of 1 to 12.

```
1   GB01530111600236    1   GB01530111600236
2   GB01530111600236    1   GB01530111600236
3   GB01530111600236    1   GB01530111600236
1   GB01530121600001    1   GB01530121600001
1   GB01530121600001    2   GB01530121600001
1   GB01530121600001    3   GB01530121600001
1   GB01530121600001    4   GB01530121600001
1   GB01530121600001    5   GB01530121600001
2   GB01530121600001    1   GB01530121600001
2   GB01530121600001    2   GB01530121600001
2   GB01530121600001    3   GB01530121600001
2   GB01530121600001    4   GB01530121600001
2   GB01530121600001    5   GB01530121600001
```

But for the second invoice number 'GB01530121600001', it's giving me duplicates.  How do I get rid of the duplicates?

TIA,

coson

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates here? The output you are getting looks like the one you are looking for. Except in the table that you are trying to generate, the IDs are showing as 1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,.... in table A for the ID ending in 001

Comment: What you are trying to get doesn't make sense to me.  Can you try to explain the logic?

Comment: what database are you using please? ("sql" isn't enough to tell us what solution alternatives are available)

Comment: @Used_By_Already, I'm using SQL Server

Comment: then always add that as a tag please.... we aren't clairvoyants

Comment: @GordonLinoff, What I'm trying to get is every combination of invoice numbers from both tables  For example if I have one invoice number in TestA that's not in TestB, then I should get 1 record from TestA with a corresponding null record in TestB.  I have have ten invoices from TestB and two invoices from TestA, then I should still get ten rows with eight null rows from TestA.  Hopefully that make some sense.

Comment: all you are missing I believe is `AND A.RowNumber = B.RowNumber` in your join condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow the logic for your result set.  The following, however, should give the same results:

```
SELECT COALESCE(A.RowNumber, 1),
       COALESCE(B.RowNumber, 1),
       COALESCE(A.InvoiceNumber, B.InvoiceNumber),
       COALESCE(A.InvoiceNumber, B.InvoiceNumber)
FROM TestA A FULL OUTER JOIN
     TestB B
     ON A.InvoiceNumber = B.InvoiceNumber AND
        A.RowNumber = B.RowNumber;
```

Comment: thank you.  This gives me exactly what I want.  In short, what I was looking for was I could have one or more invoices in either table.  I wanted every single combination of invoices to both tables.  Hopefully that make sense.